# ObjectBox Flutter MacOS

Tags: macos, flutter, dart, desktop, objectbox

How can I make objectbox-dart working also on MacOS

Flutter:
** BUILD FAILED **
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:550:9)

#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1157:12)

#3      FlutterCommand.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1009:27)

#4      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)

#5      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)

#6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:13)

#7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand. (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:278:9)

#8      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)

#9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)

#10     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:234:5)

#11     run.. (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)

#12     run. (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:12)

#13     AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)

#14     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)

#15     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:73:10)

#16     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)

Building on xCode
Error: ld: library not found for -lobjectbox

Answer (score 2):

Update: Since this answer was originally posted, ObjectBox now supports flutter-desktop out of the box. Refer to https://pub.dev/packages/objectbox#getting-started :

> For sandboxed macOS apps: specify an application group. Check all `macos/Runner/*.entitlements` files if they contain a  section with correct group ID info. Change the string value to the DEVELOPMENT_TEAM found in Xcode settings, plus an application-specific suffix, for example:
>
> ```xml
> <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
> <array>
>   <string>FGDTDLOBXDJ.demo</string>
> </array>
> ```

---

Original answer:

ObjectBox Flutter desktop support is a work-in-progress, there's a tracking GitHub issue: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues/166

For now, you have to add the ObjectBox native library `libobjectbox.dylib` manually using Xcode:

- get the library from a GitHub release: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-c/releases/download/v0.13.0/objectbox-macos-universal.zip
- Open the yourapp/macos/Runner.xcworkspace in Xcode.
- Drag your precompiled library (libyourlibrary.dylib) into Runner/Frameworks.

  - Click Runner and go to the Build Phases tab.

    - Drag `libobjectbox.dylib` into the Copy Bundle Resources list.
    - Under Bundle Framework, check Code Sign on Copy.
    - Under Link Binary With Libraries, set status to Optional.
  - Click Runner and go to the General tab.

    - Drag `libobjectbox.dylib` into the Frameworks, Libararies and Embedded Content list.
    - Select Embed & Sign.